# How to build and call a simple PHP class for a PDO DB connection

Tags: php, class, pdo

Here's what I have so far:

```
class DB {
    var $DBUser = 'xxx';
    var $DBPass = 'xxx';
    var $DBServer = 'xxx';
    var $DBName = 'xxx';

    public function connect() {
        try {  
            $strDSN = "mysql:host=$this->DBServer;dbname=$this->DBName;";  
            $username = $this->$DBUser;
            $pass = $this->$DBPass;
            $conn = new PDO($strDSN, $username, $pass);
            $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            echo 'connected';
         }   
        catch (PDOException $e) {  
            echo 'Error: ' . $e->getMessage();   
        }  
    } //end method
} //end class
```

Which is then called using this:

```
$db = new DB; 
$conn = $db->connect; 
$stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM XXX WHERE id = :id'); 
$id = $_GET['id'];
$stmt->execute(array('id'=>$id)); 
$result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

However, I'm getting this error message:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function `prepare()` on a non-object

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: 1. Don't use `var` anymore 2. `$conn = $db->connect;` Is a function so call it as one e.g. `$conn = $db->connect();` 3. class property's have to be accessed like this: `$this->DBUser;` <- See the second `$` sign is gone (Same for `$this->$DBPass;`) 4. you have to return your connection, to be able to assign it like this: `return $conn` or `return false;` if the connection fails

Comment: Also on execute you need `:id`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call a method, include the parenthesis:

```
$conn = $db->connect();
//                  ^^ missing
```

The second problem is your connect method doesn't return the connection handle. In the `try` block add:

```
return $conn;
```

Finally, when referencing instance and class properties, don't include the `$`.

```
$username = $this->DBUser;
//                 ^ $ should not be present
```

Comment: You still miss a few points. See my comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28568787/how-to-build-and-call-a-simple-php-class-for-a-pdo-db-connection#comment45447575_28568787

Comment: @Rizier123 although the use of `var` is not recommended, it doesn't impact on functionality here.

Comment: He also should return false or something like that if the connection fails so he can put it in a if statement to check it

Comment: It isn't necessary. `NULL` will be returned. In any case, I would rather have PDO raise the uncaught exception and catch it when calling connect(), because he's using exception mode for everything else, might as well use it in the connect call.

Comment: @MrCode: Thanks! How would you expand this to carry out a simple query when called with something like this: $conn = $db->connect('SELECT * FROM XXX WHERE id = :id',$_GET['id']);